# how can I cover this test class? I'm stuck at 40%

Tags: apex

I'm trying to cover at least 75% for this class and I'm losing my mind here because I don't understand why the code is not covered.. is the order of the DML not correct? I don't know.. anyways here is the class and the test class:

```
global class scheduledBatchTimeEntryForWorkDetail implements Schedulable 
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
    {
        List<SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c> workDetails = new List<SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c>(); 
        Set<Id> techIds = new Set<Id>(); 
            
        
        //run the script for all work details that are in the range of 6 months
        DateTime refDate = DateTime.Now();
        DateTime EndDateInterval =  refDate.AddDays(-180);
 
        for(SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c wd : [SELECT Id, SVMXC__Group_Member__r.SVMXC__Salesforce_User__c,SVMXC__Start_Date_and_Time__c, SVMXC__End_Date_and_Time__c,SVMX_Duration__c, SVMXC__Line_Type__c,                                        SIG_Activity_type__c, SIG_Ship_To__c, 
                                      (SELECT Id FROM SVMXC__Time_Entrys__r)  FROM SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c            
                                       WHERE (SVMXC__Line_Type__c='Labor' OR SVMXC__Line_Type__c='Travel')           
                                             AND SVMXC__Group_Member__c!=null AND SVMXC__Line_Status__c = 'Processed'           
                                             AND (SVMXC__Start_Date_and_Time__c <= :refDate AND SVMXC__Start_Date_and_Time__c >= :EndDateInterval)]) 
        {     
            if(wd.SVMXC__Time_Entrys__r.size() == 0) 
            {   
                ***workDetails.add(wd);   
                techIds.add(wd.SVMXC__Group_Member__r.SVMXC__Salesforce_User__c);***  
            } 
        } 

System.debug('### workDetails : ' + workDetails.size());

        Map<String, SVMXC__Timesheet_Day_Entry__c> dayEntries = new Map<String, SVMXC__Timesheet_Day_Entry__c>(); 
 
        for(SVMXC__Timesheet_Day_Entry__c tde : [SELECT Id, SVMXC__Timesheet__c, SVMXC__Timesheet__r.SVMXC__User__c, SVMXC__Timsheet_Day__c FROM SVMXC__Timesheet_Day_Entry__c WHERE SVMXC__Timesheet__r.SVMXC__User__c IN :techIds]) 
        {  
            String key = '' + tde.SVMXC__Timesheet__r.SVMXC__User__c + tde.SVMXC__Timsheet_Day__c;
            dayEntries.put(key, tde); 
        } 

System.debug('### dayEntries : ' + dayEntries.size()); 
 
 
        List<SVMXC__Timesheet_Entry__c> timeEntries = new List<SVMXC__Timesheet_Entry__c>(); 

        for(SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c wd : workDetails)  
        {  
            String key = '' + wd.SVMXC__Group_Member__r.SVMXC__Salesforce_User__c + wd.SVMXC__Start_Date_and_Time__c.date();  
            SVMXC__Timesheet_Day_Entry__c tde = dayEntries.get(key);  
            if(tde != null)   
            {   
               SVMXC__Timesheet_Entry__c timeEntry = new SVMXC__Timesheet_Entry__c(); 
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Timesheet__c = tde.SVMXC__Timesheet__c;   
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Timesheet_Day__c = tde.Id;   
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Work_Detail__c = wd.Id;   
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Start_Time__c = wd.SVMXC__Start_Date_and_Time__c;   
               timeEntry.SVMXC__End_Time__c = wd.SVMXC__End_Date_and_Time__c;   
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Comments__c = wd.SIG_Activity_type__c;   
               timeEntry.SIG_Is_Billable__c  = true;         
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Account__c  = wd.SIG_Ship_To__c;         
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Duration__c = wd.SVMX_Duration__c / 60;   
               timeEntries.add(timeEntry);  
            } 
        } 
 
System.debug('### timeEntries : ' + timeEntries.size()); 
 
        if(timeEntries.size() > 0)  
            insert timeEntries;
    }
}
```

And here is  the test class I've built so far:

```
@isTest
public class scheduledBatchTimeEntryForWorkDetail_UT {

static testMethod void testTimeEntryCreation()
{
    Profile fsmProf = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='SIG-FSM-Field Service Engineer' limit 1];
    User fsmUser = new User(Alias = 'testfsm1', Email='testfsm1@test.com', 
                            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='TestFSM1', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = fsmProf.Id, 
                            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='testfsm1@test.com',
                            SIG_Ticket_Recipient__c = 'AM-N - FSE', isActive=true, SIG_Is_User_Authorized__c = true);
    insert fsmUser;
    
    SVMXC__Service_Group__c serviceTeam = new SVMXC__Service_Group__c();
    serviceTeam.SVMXC__Active__c = True;
    serviceTeam.Name = 'Test Service Group';
    insert serviceTeam;
    
    SVMXC__Service_Group_Members__c tech = new SVMXC__Service_Group_Members__c();
    tech.Name='Test Tech';
    tech.SVMXC__Service_Group__c = serviceTeam.id;
    tech.SVMXC__Salesforce_User__c = fsmUser.Id;
    insert tech;
   
    
    //insert work order
    SVMXC__Service_Order__c  workOrder = new SVMXC__Service_Order__c ();
    workOrder.SVMXC__Order_Status__c  = 'Open';
    workOrder.SVMXC__Sub_Status__c = 'Unresolved';
    workOrder.SVMXC__Priority__c = 'Low';
    workOrder.SVMXC__Order_Type__c = 'Reactive';
    workOrder.SVMXC__Group_Member__c  = tech.Id;
    insert workOrder; 

             //insert timesheet
    SVMXC__Timesheet__c weekelyTimeEntries = new SVMXC__Timesheet__c();
    weekelyTimeEntries.SIG_Timesheet_Technician__c =   tech.Id;
    weekelyTimeEntries.SVMXC__Start_Date__c = System.Today();
    weekelyTimeEntries.SVMXC__User__c = fsmUser.Id;
    insert weekelyTimeEntries;
    
      
    //insert dailyEntries
    SVMXC__Timesheet_Day_Entry__c dayEntries = new SVMXC__Timesheet_Day_Entry__c();
    dayEntries.SVMXC__Timesheet__c = weekelyTimeEntries.Id;
    dayEntries.SVMXC__Timsheet_Day__c =  System.Today();
    insert dayEntries;
    
    //insert work detail
    SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c woDetail = new SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c();
    Id workDetailRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Usage/Consumption').getRecordTypeId();
    woDetail.RecordTypeId = workDetailRecordTypeId;
    woDetail.SVMXC__Service_Order__c = workOrder.Id;
    woDetail.SVMXC__Line_Type__c ='Labor';
    woDetail.SVMXC__Line_Status__c = 'Processed';
    woDetail.SVMXC__Start_Date_and_Time__c = system.today();
    woDetail.SVMXC__End_Date_and_Time__c = system.today()+1;
    woDetail.SVMXC__Group_Member__c =  tech.Id;
    insert woDetail; 
    
    
    
    //insert time entries
    SVMXC__Timesheet_Entry__c timeEntries = new SVMXC__Timesheet_Entry__c();
    timeEntries.SVMXC__Timesheet__c = weekelyTimeEntries.Id;
    timeEntries.SVMXC__Timesheet_Day__c = dayEntries.Id;
    timeEntries.SVMXC__Work_Detail__c = woDetail.Id;
    timeEntries.SVMXC__Start_Time__c = woDetail.SVMXC__Start_Date_and_Time__c;
    timeEntries.SVMXC__End_Time__c = woDetail.SVMXC__End_Date_and_Time__c;
    timeEntries.SIG_Is_Billable__c  = true;  
    insert timeEntries;
    


    
    // This test runs a scheduled job at midnight Sept. 3rd. 2022
    String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 3 9 ? 2022';
    // Schedule the test job
    String jobId = System.schedule('scheduledBatchTimeEntryForWorkDetail_UT', CRON_EXP, new scheduledBatchTimeEntryForWorkDetail());
    // Get the information from the CronTrigger API object 
     CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId]; 
    // Verify the expressions are the same System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, ct.CronExpression); 
    // Verify the job has not run 
    System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered); 
    // Verify the next time the job will run 
     System.assertEquals('2022-09-03 00:00:00', String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));   
         
 
}}
```

The lines which are not covered are the following:

```
{   
   workDetails.add(wd);   
   techIds.add(wd.SVMXC__Group_Member__r.SVMXC__Salesforce_User__c);  
}

{  
   String key = '' + tde.SVMXC__Timesheet__r.SVMXC__User__c + tde.SVMXC__Timsheet_Day__c;
   dayEntries.put(key, tde); 
} 




 {  
    String key = '' + wd.SVMXC__Group_Member__r.SVMXC__Salesforce_User__c + wd.SVMXC__Start_Date_and_Time__c.date();  
        SVMXC__Timesheet_Day_Entry__c tde = dayEntries.get(key);  
            if(tde != null)   
            {   
               SVMXC__Timesheet_Entry__c timeEntry = new SVMXC__Timesheet_Entry__c(); 
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Timesheet__c = tde.SVMXC__Timesheet__c;   
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Timesheet_Day__c = tde.Id;   
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Work_Detail__c = wd.Id;   
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Start_Time__c = wd.SVMXC__Start_Date_and_Time__c;   
               timeEntry.SVMXC__End_Time__c = wd.SVMXC__End_Date_and_Time__c;   
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Comments__c = wd.SIG_Activity_type__c;   
               timeEntry.SIG_Is_Billable__c  = true;         
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Account__c  = wd.SIG_Ship_To__c;         
               timeEntry.SVMXC__Duration__c = wd.SVMX_Duration__c / 60;   
               timeEntries.add(timeEntry);  
            }

insert timeEntries;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(wd.SVMXC__Time_Entrys__r.size() == 0) 
{   
    workDetails.add(wd);   
    techIds.add(wd.SVMXC__Group_Member__r.SVMXC__Salesforce_User__c);
}
```

If you manage to cover these lines, the other ones will be covered too because this is the only block in which you populate `techIds`, used in the query on `SVMXC__Timesheet_Day_Entry__c`, and `workDetails`, so if you never add an element to the list, you'll never cover the for-loop `for(SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c wd : workDetails)`.

The condition of the if block is pretty straightforward, the retrieved `SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c` must have no child, so you have to create no record for `SVMXC__Timesheet_Entry__c` object.
Remove of comment the following lines from your test class:

```java
//insert time entries
SVMXC__Timesheet_Entry__c timeEntries = new SVMXC__Timesheet_Entry__c();
timeEntries.SVMXC__Timesheet__c = weekelyTimeEntries.Id;
timeEntries.SVMXC__Timesheet_Day__c = dayEntries.Id;
timeEntries.SVMXC__Work_Detail__c = woDetail.Id;
timeEntries.SVMXC__Start_Time__c = woDetail.SVMXC__Start_Date_and_Time__c;
timeEntries.SVMXC__End_Time__c = woDetail.SVMXC__End_Date_and_Time__c;
timeEntries.SIG_Is_Billable__c  = true;  
insert timeEntries;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Also I don't get why I have -2 points as I'm not even a developer and I'm trying to learn by myself. Anyways...

Comment: @SarahPaulson Users can downvote a question/answer if they didn't find it useful or if it doesn't show a minimal effort of if it's too vague and so on. The [help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/asking) about asking covers several topics. For what it worth, I didn't downvoted your question because you tried to cover those lines, while sometimes new users just ask for a solution/code showing no effort at all. By the way, [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa?sort=Newest) you can find a lot of common questions with good answers

Comment: thanks for clarification.